# Doctrine persist object in two different tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm new to doctrine and have a problem to persist an object in two different tables: one which stores the current state of every car and one for historical data.

For example: the object Car has a tourNumber, a startTime, an endTime, the currentPosition and a companyId (from a Company object). I store the current tour and position in a tracking table. Now I want to store each entry additionally in a tourHistory table and I don't need the companyId but companyName (because the id for companies can change from time to time).

How would I do it with doctrine and the annotations?

Comment: I would use the loggable doctrine extension. https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new entity `TourHistory` where you would store your historical data and link it with `Car` entity with ManyToOne relation.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional